How to get the game render area geometry (Rect) within the Unity Editor? not just the GameView
I've been trying for a couple of days to obtain the geometry of the rendering area of the Unity Editor. What I mean is the Rect/Bounding-box shown in red in the following image, with its coordinates being either relative to the display geometry, or at least within its top window geometry 
There is an interesting proposal I found around as follows:
private Rect GetMainGameViewPosition()
{
    System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = typeof(EditorWindow).Assembly;
    Type type = assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView");
    EditorWindow gameview = EditorWindow.GetWindow(type);
    return gameview.position;
}

However, after much trial and error, I've found that this is returning what is intended to be the Rect shown in yellow in the picture. I write below an explanation of why I say "intended", but my key question remains:
How do I programmatically retrieve the geometry of the area in red? The solution needs to consider the current scale (eg. 1x-10x) and panning.
Motivation: if you are curious of why I need this, it's because I have an eye tracker device whose coordinates are available in relation to the display, and I need to map them in real-time to the area in red so I can relate the eye tracking input to game content.
The reason why I say "intended" is because I've come across unexpected behavior: I'm logging into console the retrieved geometry of "GameView" (x:472, y:73, width:1447, height:656) and while the width and height accurately match the yellow area (note it contains part of the control bar), the x, y only seem to match the point on the top-left of the "Scene/Game" tab selection area, and that's why I drew the green rectangle (exactly of size 472x73) where I did. Note that this interpretation is not fixed by moving the green rectangle to the top-left point of the "File" button.

so you want to know whats rendered in the gameview? would you not use camera bounds, and some sreenpointtoray to tell where that lands in geometry?

not quite. Ignoring for a moment the game contents, and such tricks, and just treating the Unity Editor as just a windows application. As a Window, it will have some geometry stating where it is shown on your display. That's easy to find for the top window of the Unity Editor. However, I want to dig in further and I want to get the geometry of the box in red, in relation to the top window.

Well its still the camera size, Camera.main.pixelWidth &  Camera.main.pixelHeight report accurate scene window size

that gives resolution of the game rendering, yes. But it does not comprise the scale selected by the user in the viewer. Also, it does not provide the translation (x, y) or "offset" of that rectangle in relation to the top level window (whether the top-left most point, or the bottom-left most point).

have you read https://forum.unity.com/threads/game-window-scale.539919/ ? which covers how to get the scale?

All the information you need is contained in the source code.  https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/GameView/GameView.cs
